# SOAPUI - Insert a collection of objects in a single value field

Tags: soapui

How can I insert this collection of objects into a single value? (for a POST request)

```
"data": {
    "Idtest": 1,
    "Nametest": "test",
    "OBJECT" : {
                  "ID":1,
                   "NameTest": "BLA"
                }
  }
```

- The parameter is: OBJECT.
- And I want to insert in a value field this collection: {"ID":1,
  "NameTest": "BLA" }

Is this step possible in SOAPUI?

Comment: Didn't quite get your question... could you explain it with a little clarity? :)
Is this what you want? {"ID":1, "NameTest": "BLA", "value": "123"}

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
[image]

Does it help?

Maybe you want to send parameter "data", then it should be like:
[image]